# Telnet / Terminal commands

Tags: terminal, command, telnet, terminal-emulator

Got a problem with a proxy telnet server that I am trying to debug, it appears that a set of characters being sent are causing it a problem .... does anybody know where I can get a list of teminal commands (Along the lines of [40m)?

Answer (score 2):

You have to do telnet negotiation, did you checked [RFC-1091](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1091.txt) and [RFC-854](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc854.txt)?  Afterwards, what will be accepted depends on the terminal type of course.

Answer (score 0):

For telnet protocol, you could lookup [RFC854](http://www.isi.edu/in-notes/rfc854.txt). But from your description, you are probably looking for specifications of some terminal emulators. There are a lot of different terminal types, each having its own specifications.